# Android code for change a marker position with out focusing it

Tags: android, google-maps

In my application I want to update my marker on each 5 seconds. Problem is each time the marker get updated, it get focused. Suppose I am looking for a place in America and if the marker located in India get updated, then map automatically focus to India and that affects my search in America. How to update a marker with out focusing it?

Comment: could you reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle or in a snippet inside the question?

Comment: please add code for more details